# Add paging for user activity section

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, users, recent-activity

I'm curious, are people interested in paging on the [recent activity page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174?tab=activity#tab-top)?

Comment: Well @Geoff did it ... awesome :)

Comment: WOW. Full history, too.

Comment: Very nice! It's not search per se, but I'm beyond satisfied with this implementation since it lets me track revisions, comments, and everything else I'd need very comfortably! Three cheers for Geoff!

Comment: I have this uncontrollable urge to upvote Geoff. Any chance he could post an answer here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is completed - enjoy!

Comment: What, no improbable tale about how you had to scale the peak of Mt. Abidjijibi and battle mutant goats for the talisman of power in order to implement this?

Comment: Are we supposed to be able to go back to the very first activity?  On cstheory, I can go back to almost the first activity but not the very first.

Answer (score 4):

I think an ability to search through past comments would be far more useful than paging. As it stands, each day accumulates more activity than one page. I've only been around for 75 days about, and that yields a whopping 75 pages of stuff to try and find one comment in. I imagine that any of the much older users, subsequently, have much larger page counts. So keeping the whole history paged, while it technically has its uses, I doubt that anyone will really be able to make good use out of it.

Subsequently, if it's only going to go back a few pages, I am rarely of need to extend past the most recent day's worth of material. Anything within the past week I can usually find via the Recent Activity envelope.

So I'd say it'd be useful, I just don't know that it'd really be useful to any good degree.

---

Aside from comments, the only other thing your activity summary tracks better than your profile page or envelope report is revisions you make. While I'm still of the opinion that some ability to search your activity will be far more useful than trying to page through it all, if [the same-summary revision merging issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52967/same-summary-revisions-should-not-be-merged-in-the-activity-tab-of-a-users-profi) was removed, paging would be much more useful even without the ability to search.

Comment: The main reason I would find it useful is for stalking Eric Lippert :)  Don't we already allow you to search through comments with the special comments verbs?

Comment: @waffles: Subscribe to his user feed?

Comment: @Jon, Well yerp, but .... that would be a bit of a commitment :)

Comment: @waffles Special comment verbs? Last I checked search on the site didn't touch comments at all, only post bodies, titles, and tags. If there's been the ability to sift through all of my old comments, I've been greatly missing out.

Comment: I don't always remember what I said in a comment, sometimes I'm just remembering the question and I want to find it again. Being able to scan a list is essential. Not to say that searching comments isn't useful, but it's not a complete substitute.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely have interest in this; the first time I saw the lack of it, I was rather distraught.  It's good for referencing a comment you recently left, or similar things like that.  Things that might otherwise be lost in history forever<sub>ever<sub>*ever*...</sub></sub>

...You *are* suggesting that the pages go back to forever, right?

Comment: yerp, standard paging like we have in the rest of the site

Answer (score 1):

### Great idea

I can't count how many times I've gone back to try and find something only to be limited by answers I've given or questions I've asked rather then comments.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm looking for something I remember doing a couple of days ago, I can't find it because the activity tab only shows a limited number of entries. I'd love to see a paged view so that I can go back once the event has scrolled off the bottom.