# Question revisions repeated on user profile activity revision tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, activity-summary

The [new user profile activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55291/add-paging-for-user-activity-section) is awesome, but there's one thing that's weird about it - the revision tab seems to display more than one revision for each revision:

[image]

Studying the bug more carefully, it seems that a new revision is displayed for each of the three parts of a post - title, tag and body - that is revised.

Additionally, if you open up a revision, then close it again, it appears to be impossible to reopen it - the revision pops open, but closes immediately. This occurs on Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I was originally going to report this under a different bug, but it turns out your report is what seems to actually happen. Go search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisions are now collapsed and expanding now works properly.