# Change comment help for link markdown

Tags: feature-request, comments, editing-help

This is the help for comments:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)
>   _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user
>   name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…

I've stumbled often over `[link](http://example.com)` because the `link` is not the "link", but the text that **is** linked. I often find myself putting the URL in the link part because it is confusing.

## Proposed changes

Here are two alternatives to make the help text for that tag a bit clearer; maybe the community can identify better ones.

### option 1

```
[text](http://example.com)
```

### option 2

```
[text](url)
```

What do you think?

Comment: +1 And while this might be immediately obvious to the more tech savvy, note that there are now many sites in SE where the audience might be misled by this description.

Comment: +1! I was just working on a question about this, it has bugged me a couple of times. Wish I could bump it 8)