# Tweak the help text for how to make links on comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, editing-help, help-text

Could we get the help text for comments tweaked a tiny bit?  I always find `[link](http://www.example.com)` confusing, because http://www.example.com **is** a link.

Just now, I actually went to one of my answers and posted a comment so I could experiment with it and not disturb anyone.

If you could just change it to `[link text](http://www.example.com)`, I'd never be confused again.

I'll be the first to admit, this is a very similar question to [Change comment help for link markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151859/change-comment-help-for-link-markdown), but that one didn't seem to generate much impact, so I'm hoping this one will.

This is what I currently see on SO:

```
Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)
_italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To  also notify a previous commenter, mention their user
name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this?  I see `Here's [a link](http://www.example.com/)` in the markup editor help.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually, both on here and on SO, I see [link](http://example.com).  I'll paste the block as I see it in the question.

Comment: Ah, there it is.  It's in the Help link for the comment text box.  Seems pretty clear to me.  Why do you guys keep getting tripped up over little details like this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because they're there?  ;-)